# Favicon is not recognized on apache2 ubuntu server

Tags: html, ubuntu, apache2, favicon

No matter what I do, I am unable to link the favicon to its website. I've tried using a png in a subfolder and linked it appropriately. It worked perfectly fine on windows, but after I've transferred the folder and the html files to my apache2 ubuntu server, it doesn't show anymore. I have even tried to just use a file named "favicon.ico" and placed it in the root, but this doesn't work either, even when explicitly referring to it in the html file with a link. No matter what I do, the icon isn't shown. I've tried this with a 64x64 sized png and a 32x32 version of it, so the size can't be problem.

Comment: Hey, I am guessing it's in /var/www/html/ which is usually the root. Is there another folder inside html? If yes it's probably a path issue.

Comment: @billybadass, first it was located in another folder in the root (/var/www/html/ another_folder), but as it didn't work, I moved it to the root. So it should have been possible to address it in html with href="favicon.ico" (or a different name or format), when the html file is is placed in the root too.

Answer (score 0):

@tarquinius - the favicon must be in the same folder as your installation, it can't be a level up. If that is true and they are all in the root folder you could to try: "http://localhost/favicon.ico" Let me know!